# Issue with exporting i18n in cake 2.3

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to do an export of the pot file. Everything is running fine until I get this error:

```
Class OscProductRelationshipRelation does not exist
#0 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-
2.3/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php(446): ReflectionClass-
>__construct('OscProductRelat...')
#1 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-
2.3/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php(281): ExtractTask-
>_extractValidationMessages()
#2 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-
2.3/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php(232): ExtractTask->_extract()
#3 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-2.3/Cake/Console/Shell.php(388): 
ExtractTask->execute()
#4 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-2.3/Cake/Console/Shell.php(385): Shell-
>runCommand('execute', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-2.3/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(199):  
Shell->runCommand('extract', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-2.3/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(67):  
ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/html/cakephp/cakephp-2.3/Cake/Console/cake.php(43): 
ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
```

I did not find anything online about this error. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Cleared cache, didn't solve the problem

Comment: Do you have OscProductRelationshipRelationController.php file and OscProductRelationshipRelation class ?